# Combination of two mod_rewrite rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I´ve already read many questions related to this topic, but I could´t find a solution. I want to combine two mod_rewrite rules:

1. ... /filename.html **to** ... /index.php?page=filename
2. ... /article/name **to** ... /index.php?article=name

To do so, I´ve created the following two rules:

1. `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ index.php?page=$1`
2. `RewriteRule ^article/(.*)\.html$ index.php?article=$1`

Both of them are working fine as long as they are used alone. I thought that the error may occur because of the first rule, which rewrites every URL also the URLs with /article/..., that´s why I´ve tried the following, but it still doesn´t work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^article/(.*)\.html$ index.php?article=$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/articles$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ index.php?page=$1
```

If I trie to go to **... /test.html** I already get **... /index.php?page=test** but if I type in **... /article/test.html** I only get **... /index.php?page=index.php/test** instead of **... /index.php?article=test**.

In addition I dont´t want it to rewrite anything stored in **/admin**, but `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/admin$` doesn´t work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution on my own. The condition in line 3 was false, it should actually say `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/article/(.*)\.html$` in order to include everything inside the the directory **... /article/** and not only **... /article/** itself.